# Tailwindcss 2 style is not working in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, tailwind-css

I am trying out Tailwindcss to a new Angular 11 project. I have the following dev packages installed.

```
NOTE: Removed other packages for simplicity
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^10.0.1",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.2",
"@angular/cli": "~11.0.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.1",
"autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
"postcss-import": "^13.0.0",
"postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
"postcss-scss": "^3.0.4",
"tailwindcss": "^2.0.1",
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            ident: 'postcss',
            syntax: 'postcss-scss',
            plugins: () => [
              require('postcss-import'),
              require('tailwindcss'),
              require('autoprefixer')
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

style.scss

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

angular.json

```
"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser", //dev-server
"customWebpackConfig": { "path": "webpack.config.js" }
```

I added this code to `app.component.html` but it seems like it does not recognize the styles.

```
...... some codes not included
<div class="px-6 pb-4 space-x-2">
    <a href="https://angular.io" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"
      class="inline-block bg-red-500 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-white hover:bg-red-700">
      #angular
    </a>
    <a href="https://tailwindcss.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"
      class="inline-block bg-indigo-500 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-white hover:bg-indigo-700">
      #tailwind
    </a>
    <a href="https://notiz.dev" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer"
      class="inline-block bg-blue-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 hover:bg-blue-400">
      #notiz
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could update to beta version
**@angular-builders/custom-webpack**. It has new changes in your **angular.json** the section *customWebpackConfig* should now be like so

```
 "customWebpackConfig": {
      "path": "./webpack.config.js",
      "mergeRules": {
           "module": {
              "rules": "append"
            }
      }
  }
```

The webpack.config.js your loaders should be like

```
let sass;
try {
  sass= require('node-sass');
} catch {
  sass= require('sass');
}

module.exports = {
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                syntax: 'postcss-scss',
                plugins: [
                  "postcss-import",
                  "tailwindcss",
                  "autoprefixer"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              implementation: sass,
              sourceMap: false,
              sassOptions: {
                precision: 8
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

You could read more about this on [angular-builders](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/908)

also the packages you will need

- "postcss": "^8.2.1"
- "postcss-import": "^14.0.0"
- "postcss-loader": "^4.1.0"
- "postcss-scss": "^3.0.4"
- "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2"
- "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0"
- "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^11.0.0-beta.4"

Answer (score 2):

The ngneat/tailwind thing doesn't work for Angular v11.2.0 and above.
Webpack won't load the tailwind and hence styles won't be applied. It kind of cumulatively wasted our team's 12+ hours, becasue in npm angular version was set to "~11.2.0" and one of team member had local cache for "11.1.x", and hence the lower version was picked by npm and ngneat based setup was working, giving a false impression that ng neat works for 11.2.0 and problem is with our own setup.

After this ordeal, the idea of confirming "the actual package version installed" got re-enforced.

Install with `npm install -D tailwindcss`

Install TailwindCSS plugins(Optional):

```
npm i @tailwindcss/typography

npm i @tailwindcss/forms
```

Some people are running older versions of the CLI or the @angular-devkit/build-angular. Make sure your package.json looks AT LEAST with version 11.2.0this or have a more recent versions (if available)

Create a TailwindCSS configuration file in the workspace or project root. Name that configuration file tailwind.config.js
It should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    prefix: '',
    purge: {
      content: [
        './src/**/*.{html,ts}',
      ]
    },
    darkMode: 'class', // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    variants: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms'),require('@tailwindcss/typography')],
};
```

In your styles.scss file add the following TailwindCSS imports

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

If you are using CSS[`.css`] instead of SCSS[`.scss`], your file should look like this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I took this from an amazing piece by this person here:

https://dev.to/angular/setup-tailwindcss-in-angular-the-easy-way-1i5l

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 11+ , the problem is postcss is not able to find the tailwind.config.js file.

To solve the issue (Not documented in Tailwind's official docs):

1. Add a new file called postcss.config.js (src)
2. Include the following lines:

   ```
   module.exports = {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: { config: './src/tailwind.config.js' },
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
   ```

   }